# React Cloudinary Image upload issue re: state and axios calls to Cloudinary and MongoDb database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, image, cloudinary

My question: how do I make sure state for the image gets set to the response secure url from Cloudinary before my axios post to mongodb to avoid an undefined state and a path validation issue for the image field in my mongodb model?

I'm having a similar issue to the one described in this post:

[React-native Cloudinary image upload problem with state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70292816/react-native-cloudinary-image-upload-problem-with-state/76933877#76933877)

I'm trying to upload an image in React with Cloudinary and I think there's a firing order issue with my axios calls affecting a proper database post. Looking at my console logs, the first handleSubmit  for a POST request to MongoDb includes state  for the image set to its initial useState  value of `{cloudinaryImg:''}`, so I get a validation issue. The console log for the axios post to Cloudinary confirms that state does get set to the url sent back in the response. I also see the image in cloudinary. So the first time I click submit when I navigate into that component, I get the POST failture, but then the second time I click it works and the image renders. Looking at the console logs, that second time around the state is now the url from the previous time I clicked submit. So I am able to display an image, but I'm an image behind. I've tried having only one function being called when submitting. I've tried nesting the axios calls. Nothing has been working but I feel pretty sure based on the console log issues and the fact I can render images in the component that there's a firing order issue.

Please let me know if you would like to see any other file.

This is my component for creating installation steps, each step including text and an image. Please ignore the msgAlert in the catch, as I'm still working on failure messages:

Installation Step component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Modal, Form, Button, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import createOneStep from '../../api/installationSteps'
import Axios from 'axios'

const CreateInstallationStepModal = (props) => {
    const { show, handleClose, triggerRefresh, user, car, aftermarketPartId } = props
    //need to write handleChange, handleSubmit, as well as pass installation step
    // to the car form
    const [step, setStep] = useState({ step:''})
    const [stepImage, setStepImage] = useState({cloudinaryImg:''})
    const [ imageSelected, setImageSelected ] = useState('')
    const initialStepState = { step: ''}
    console.log('this is imageSelected', imageSelected)
    

    const upload = () => {
        const cloud_name = process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUD_NAME
        const cloud_upload_preset = process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUD_UPLOAD_PRESET
        const formData = new FormData()
        console.log('this is imageSelected',imageSelected)
        formData.append("file", imageSelected)
        formData.append('upload_preset', cloud_upload_preset)
        // initialImageState =  formData.append("file", imageSelected)
         Axios.post(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloud_name}/image/upload`, formData)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('this is response data.secure_url',response.data.secure_url)
                setStepImage(response.data.secure_url)
            })    
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.persist()

        setStep(prevStep => {
            const name = e.target.name
            let value = e.target.value
            const updatedValue = { [name]: value }
            // console.log('this is prevStep', prevStep)
            // console.log('this is updatedValue', updatedValue)
            // console.log('this is step', step)
            return { ...prevStep, ...updatedValue }
        } )
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        console.log('this is stepImage to be submitted', stepImage)

        createOneStep(user, car, aftermarketPartId, step, stepImage)
            .then(()=> handleClose())
            .then(()=> triggerRefresh())
            .then(() => setStep(initialStepState))
            .catch(() => {
                // msgAlert({
                //     heading: 'No cars?!!',
                //     message: indexCarsFailure,
                //     variant: 'danger',
                // })
            })
    }
    console.log('this is stepImage', stepImage)
    return (
        <Container>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header></Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <h3>blah</h3>
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Label>Step</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            placeholder="Step"
                            value={step.step}
                            name="step"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <Form.Label>Image</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="file"
                            onChange={(e) => {setImageSelected(e.target.files[0])}}
                        /> 
                        <Button onClick={()=>upload()} type='submit'>submit</Button>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </Container>
    )
}
export default CreateInstallationStepModal
```

This is the file I created for axios calls. You'll find the function to createOneStep that is called in previous code block above:

```
import apiUrl from '../apiConfig'
import axios from 'axios'

//create one step

const createOneStep = (user,car, aftermarketPartId, installationStep, stepImage) => {
//     console.log('this is user in axios call', user)
//   console.log('this is installationStep', installationStep)
//   console.log('this is car.id', car.id)
//   console.log('this is aftermarketPart.id', aftermarketPartId)
    return axios ({
        url: apiUrl + `/installationStep/${car.id}/${aftermarketPartId}`,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Token token=${user.token}`
        },
        data: { 
            installationStep: {
                step: installationStep.step,
                cloudinaryImg: stepImage
            }
        }
        
    })
}

export const deleteOneStep = (user,carId, deletedAftermarketPartId, installationStepId) => {
    console.log('this is carid in axios', carId)
    console.log('this is aftermarketPart Id in axios file', deletedAftermarketPartId)
    console.log('this is installationStepId in axios file', installationStepId)
    return axios({
        url:`${apiUrl}/installationStep/${carId}/${deletedAftermarketPartId}/${installationStepId}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers:{
            Authorization: `Token token=${user.token}`
        }
    })
}

export default createOneStep
```